# Include local maven dependencies when exporting android library

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I know from some other answers that including dependencies into an aar library is discouraged as the one using the aar should be able to include them by himself.

But I have a bunch of local maven dependencies that I would like to include with the aar. I could of course just include the .jar's. But there is a quite a few dependencies and if I update them I need to get all separate jars and update them as well in my aar. And using compile 'maven repo...' is quite handy.

So my question is, can I some how force my local maven repos to be included in the .aar?

Comment: force your entire maven repo into your `aar` ? Do you mean, how to include all your dependencies inside the `aar` ?

Comment: Thats exactly what I mean.